# ValueError: Not a valid PEM pre boundary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycrypto, pem

this piece of code

```
key=RSA.importKey(open("receiver.pem","rb").read())
```

returns this error

```
ValueError: Not a valid PEM pre boundary
```

and

```
key=RSA.importKey(open("receiver.pem","r").read())
```

returns

```
ValueError: Not a valid PEM post boundary
```

The code worked fine when we used Pycrypto and Python 2.7, now i have shifted to Pycryptodome and Python 3.4.3(using 2to3). But now this code won't work. I can't even try anything because i can't even understand what it means.

To generate the .PEM file this code was used.

```
random_generator = Random.new().read
rsakey = RSA.generate(1024, random_generator)
f=open(email+'.pem','wb')
f.write(rsakey.exportKey("PEM"))
f.write(rsakey.publickey().exportKey("PEM"))
f.close()
```

This is what the contents of a .PEM file is like.

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----------BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCIQhU/+nPVFgw+T0Tf7NEpHYB1
2I/qywo5xBdp5kaLxEHD9zOx2FTOX2OMPiL7fv/PW/AXuSrvD3pZAFzGmkigWdQP
6TES5ZM65LUzeUUy8noHkZ00D4mz+4a4YtBGaFyNL2CCxOAczi9rx5UB6qbY6+5k
kBNd7k75XDp28g2bjwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: What module are you using ? What does the doc says about the method `importKey` ?

Comment: Does it matter that the file is opened in binary mode?

Comment: Does the first line of your PEM have something that would match `"\s*-----BEGIN (.*)-----\n"`? See [the source](https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/blob/master/lib/Crypto/IO/PEM.py#L114). If you've opened a windows file in binary mode it may have `\r\n` and therefore not match.

Comment: @tmoreau Module as in? I have used PyCryptodome. I don't know what exactly do you mean by 'module'? sorry i am a noob.

Comment: @PeterWood It returns a different answer. I have updated my question. "rb" though is the intended mode to open the file in.

Comment: Is that private key meant to be private?

Comment: Umm yes to any other device or system or person . I created this pair of keys to explain my question in a better way so i think It'll be okay to post it here.

Comment: Are you on windows? If you open in `'rb'` mode the first line might end with `\r\n`, depending on how it was created, so will not match. You need to open in `'r'` mode.

Comment: Yes I am on Windows but opening in "r" mode returns a different error(I have updated my question). When i used python 2.7 and PyCrypto it didn't make a difference whether it was "rb" or  "r".

Comment: I think you need a newline between `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` and `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----`. How did you generate the PEM?

Comment: I added a newline using "f.write(bytes("\n",'UTF-8'))" but it doesn't make any difference. I have updated the question with code used to generate the .pem file

Comment: If you read the [source code](https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome/blob/b179fa4136bb8dd48120b876915b7307fedf8b0c/lib/Crypto/IO/PEM.py#L105) you'll see that Pycryptodome expects `END RSA ...` to be on its own line

Comment: It is in a line of it's own as you can see in the question. and adding a newline character makes no difference. could you suggest what kind of changes would make my code work?

Comment: I tried and it appears that Pycryptodome cannot parse a PEM cert with two keys: it wants the final boundary to be at the end of the string (not at the end of the line as I wrote). In fact `$` in a non-multiline regex means "end of the string". The only options you have are either split the two keys, or fix Pycryptodome

Comment: ... or use PyCrypto. It works with Python 3.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini I had trouble installing it with python 3.4.3 x64. Splitting the keys has indeed solved the problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting that error because of [this function](https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome/blob/b179fa4136bb8dd48120b876915b7307fedf8b0c/lib/Crypto/IO/PEM.py#L105):

```
def decode(pem_data, passphrase=None):
    ...

    # Verify Pre-Encapsulation Boundary
    r = re.compile("\s*-----BEGIN (.*)-----\n")
    m = r.match(pem_data)
    if not m:
        raise ValueError("Not a valid PEM pre boundary")
    marker = m.group(1)

    # Verify Post-Encapsulation Boundary
    r = re.compile("-----END (.*)-----\s*$")
    m = r.search(pem_data)
    if not m or m.group(1) != marker:
        raise ValueError("Not a valid PEM post boundary")
```

Unfortunately, in non-multiline regular expressions, `$` means "end of the string". This implies that PyCryptoDome expects the `END` boundary at the end of the string, and there are no ways to work around this problem.

You have three options:

- split the two keys and import them separately;
- fix PyCryptoDome;
- switch back to PyCrypto.

Answer (score 0):

As [Peter Wood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1084416/peter-wood) commented previously, the issue is the end-of-line format.

I'm working on a project using python 2.7 in CentOS, and I've got a publickey from a website, which gave me the above error.

The problem was that it came with \r\n end of line sequence, which made the python-jose library jwt.decode call to pyCripto library fail.

My fix was to just remove '\r' character before returning the response this way:

```
<pre>
response = get(url).content
return response.replace('\r', '')
```

And this made the thing work at last. Hope this help!